# ASP.Net Postback not working in JQuery Nyromodal popup

Tags: asp.net, jquery, postback, nyromodal

I have a Default.aspx page which loads a popup using JQuery Nyromodal popup.
Within the popup I have  which needs to postback on clicking the button.

But when I click on the button in the popup window,  URL in main window is replaced with popup window URL and also the data in modal popup is not posting back.

Thanks

Comment: How is the function of the click event in the button of the popup window? and is it a button or tag "<a>?

Comment: It's an ASP.Net Image button control.
<asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="img/b-save.png" ID="btn_Save" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Save_Click"/>

Also written a Jquery function like this:
   $(function(){$('#btn_Save').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();if (confirm('Submit')){$.nyroModalManual({url: 'Add-Support-Staff.aspx'
});}return false;});});

When I click the button it is showing the confirmation, but the postback event on button click is not working.

My purpose is to post the data filled in the form to database and close the popup and return to parent window.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() 
 {   
     $('#btn_Save').click( function(e)   
     {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (confirm('Submit'))
          {
               $.nyroModalManual({url: 'Add-Support-Staff.aspx' });
          }else
          {
                return false;
          }  
     });

});
```